# In iOS program, my static table cell doesn't respond at click event but swipe

Tags: ios, uitableview, push, segue

I have an iOS project in Xcode.

It has a standard `UITableView` and I made a static `UITableViewController` in a storyboard.

I added a push segue from a `UITableViewCell` to another `UITableViewController`.

But it's weird; Click events don't respond properly.. Specifically, the cell doesn't respond with the first touch event. But the segue does work by swiping (to left or right).

I never added anything for the swipe cause a segue.
I only added selection issue(push) for segue..

I have always use this method without issue until now so I'm a bit confused..

Do you have any idea what is causing this??

Comment: Have you added any other gesture recognizers to the Nib?

Comment: shame.. i added UITapGestureRecognizer at this view controller. Thanks Acey :)

Comment: Same problem I had.  I've added the gesture recognizer in order to allow tap-dismissal of the keyboard.  Now I'll just enable the recognizer only when the keyboard is up and remove it when the keyboard is not on screen.  More work but solves this problem.  Thanks!